# How to install git-cola in cygwin?

Tags: git, cygwin, pyqt

This might be a stupid question, however I can't get it working.

I [know](ftp://sourceware.org/pub/cygwinports/portslist.txt) it has been ported. I've [found](http://artfiles.org/cygwin.org/pub/cygwinports/release-2/QtDesktop/git-cola/) both the sources and the binaries. I've downloaded all the files from [here](http://artfiles.org/cygwin.org/pub/cygwinports/release-2/QtDesktop/git-cola/) and tried cygwin setup from the download directory. I
also extracted the sources and tried `make` and whatever and nothing worked.

```
Sorry, you do not seem to have PyQt4 installed.
Please install it before using git-cola.
e.g.:    sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

```
python setup.py build
PyQt4 version 4.4 or newer required.  Found None
Makefile:32: recipe for target `all' failed
```

I do have the package "python-pyqt", version 4.9.6-1. I've tried reinstalling it, etc., and googling didn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

python-pyqt4 has a *large* dependency tree, and if you installed these packages manually, you are probably missing one or more (sub)dependencies.

Please follow the Cygwin Ports [installation directions](http://cygwinports.org/), selecting the `git-cola` package for installation, and being sure to allow `setup.exe` to install *all* dependencies when asked.

Answer (score 0):

Or install the Windows version (with its dependencies on pythonw and pyqt), it is simpler and doesn't look totally crap.

https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola/blob/master/README.md#windows-installation

(Get the latest 2.x x86_64 version of Python, and corresponding PyQt version - for me this was 'PyQt4-4.10.3-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.5-x64.exe')

You can invoke it from cygwin quite easily, here's a script that I put in my ~/bin folder as 'git-cola' (it thus resides in front of PATH):

```
#!/bin/sh

GITCOLA=`which --skip-tilde git-cola`
GITCOLA_WIN=`cygpath -w "$GITCOLA"`

/cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe "$GITCOLA_WIN" $@
```